# Does the repositioning of 'it' and 'that' (as No.2 ) introduce a nuance in the meaning?

Tags: grammar

1. She praises me and might not realise it, and I like that.
2. She praises me and might not realise that, and I like it.

Comment: Where is this from? It seems strange that almost the [same question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/537459/do-both-sentences-have-the-same-meaning) was asked by another user just a few hours ago.

Comment: [This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/159475/it-vs-this-vs-that) from ell.stackexchange.com might enlighten

Comment: The first sounds more natural to me. Less formal. I think 'She praises me and might not realise this' is more reasonable if a more formal version be felt necessary, though I'd match registers with 'and I like that about her' or 'and I can't say I'm displeased'.